# Tap Gesture does not always work

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap

I have a NSObject that instantiate a view with a UITapGestureRecognizer added. Something goes wrong because the tap works only sometimes...

```
#import "Monument.h"

@implementation Monument

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame itiName:(NSString *)itiName itiPay:(BOOL)itiPay available:(BOOL)available imageName:(NSString *)imageName viewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        self.itiName = itiName;
        self.itiPay = itiPay;
        self.itiImage = imageName;
        self.controller = controller;
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if (! [defaults boolForKey:itiName])
        {
            self.buy = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            self.buy = YES;
        }
        self.x = frame.origin.x;
        self.y = frame.origin.y;
        self.available = available;
    }
    return self;
}

-(UIView *)drawView
{
    UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed:self.itiImage];
    UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:background];
    backgroundView.frame = self.view.frame;
    backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
    // Inzializzo la Label del titolo
    UILabel *titolo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.x+8.0f, self.y+2.0f, 180.0f, 20.0f)];
    titolo.text = self.itiName;
    titolo.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:titolo];

    UIImage *imageFreeOrPayOrBought;
    if (! self.buy)
    {
        if (self.itiPay)
        {
            imageFreeOrPayOrBought = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pay-ipad"];
        }
        else
        {
            imageFreeOrPayOrBought = [UIImage imageNamed:@"free-ipad"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // già comprato
        imageFreeOrPayOrBought = [UIImage imageNamed:@"free-ipad"];
    }
    UIImageView *payOrFree = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFreeOrPayOrBought];
    CGRect frameImage = CGRectMake(self.x, self.y+117.0f, 214.5f, 20.8f);
    payOrFree.frame = frameImage;
    payOrFree.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:payOrFree];

    // Controllo se disponibile o meno
    if (! self.available)
    {
        self.view.layer.opacity = .3f;
    }

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return self.view;
}

-(void)tapRecognized: (UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    if (! self.available)
    {
       // [self openUnavailableService];
        NSLog(@"Service unavailable");
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.buy)
        {
            //[self openMonumentHomePage];
            NSLog(@"Service bought");
        }
        else
        {
            if (self.itiPay)
            {
                //[self openPurchaseInApp];
                NSLog(@"Service to buy");
            }
            else
            {
                //[self downloadDataForFree];
                NSLog(@"Service to free download");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And that's how I use the class

```
self.arrayOfMonuments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(568.0f, 640.0f);
Monument *foroRomano = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"FORO ROMANO" itiPay:NO available:YES imageName:@"fori-romano-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:foroRomano];
UIView *foroRomanoView = [foroRomano drawView];
[self.scroll addSubview:foroRomanoView];
Monument *colosseo = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0f, 0.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"COLOSSEO" itiPay:NO available:YES imageName:@"colosseo-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:colosseo];
[self.scroll addSubview:[colosseo drawView]];
Monument *appiaAntica = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 80.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"APPIA ANTICA" itiPay:YES available:NO imageName:@"appia-antica-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:appiaAntica];
UIView *appiaAnticaView = [appiaAntica drawView];
[self.scroll addSubview:appiaAnticaView];
Monument *esquilino = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0f, 80.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"ESQUILINO" itiPay:YES available:NO imageName:@"esquilino-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:esquilino];
[self.scroll addSubview:[esquilino drawView]];
Monument *palatino = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 160.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"PALATINO" itiPay:YES available:NO imageName:@"palatino-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:palatino];
[self.scroll addSubview:[palatino drawView]];
Monument *laterano = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0f, 160.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"LATERANO" itiPay:YES available:NO imageName:@"laterano-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:laterano];
[self.scroll addSubview:[laterano drawView]];
Monument *foriImperiali = [[Monument alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 240.0f, 217.1f, 117.0f) itiName:@"FORI IMPERIALI" itiPay:YES available:NO imageName:@"fori-imperiali-ipad" viewController:self];
[self.arrayOfMonuments addObject:foriImperiali];
[self.scroll addSubview:[foriImperiali drawView]];
```

How can it happens? Thanks a lot

EDIT: I also tried to replacee the UITapGesture with a UIButton, but problem still presents

```
UIButton *monumentBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
monumentBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:monumentBtn];
[monumentBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecognized:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

EDIT: I noticed that the x/y coordinates that I pass to init method are wrong because the first frame's height is 117.0f and the view that is positioned under this has 80.0f y origin. That's strange, and that's why the Tap does not always work. How can I solve this issue?

RE-EDIT: I solved with a mapping of the screen...unfortunately I didn't find other solutions.

Comment: try by adding the tap gesture in `-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame itiName:(NSString *)itiName itiPay:(BOOL)itiPay available:(BOOL)available imageName:(NSString *)imageName viewController:(UIViewController *)controller` method

Comment: @Shan It seems like the frame I passed to UIButton isn't the effective I use, because now it works only in the top-left vertex of the frame